# Compare variables ignoring multiple spaces and newline

Tags: bash, sh

I have two variables.

OUTPUT

```
s10     21
s11     5

Program terminated by dropping off the bottom.
s10     21
s11     5
```

and RESULTS

```
s10 21 s11 5
```

s10 has the value 21 and s11 has the value 5. I want to compare them and check whether the RESULTS string is in the OUTPUT string. I'm having trouble with that.

Doing this `[[ "$OUTPUT" == *"$RESULTS"* ]]` returns false.

I have also tried an approach with tr basically removing multiple whitespaces.

When I do `echo $OUTPUT` in the terminal, everything is printed in one line with single whitespaces and no newline characters.

```
s10 21 s11 5 Program terminated by dropping off the bottom. s10 21 s11 5
```

If I do `echo "$OUTPUT"` the original formatting is kept and printed.

What would be the best way to check whether OUTPUT contains RESULTS without taking into account multiple spaces and newlines?

Comment: As with `"$OUTPUT" == *"$RESULTS"*`, the result comes back always as false.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `echo` might be handy, or if you want something probably more predictable in other case you cam do

```
if tr -s '\n' ' ' <<<"$OUTPUT" | grep -q -- "$RESULT"
then
    echo 'yes'
fi
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this always returns true regardless of the actual values.